# Store images to a collection in mongodb from an input in HTML and using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, mongodb, input

I'm following the Meteor Tuturial (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) and adapting it to my case.

I created a collection in mongdob where I save lots of inputs made by an user, most of them are strings. Here are some lines as example:

HTML

```
<template name="inputform">
   <form class="new-task">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Type to add name" />
   </form>
</template>
```

Java Script

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
Template.inputform.events({
"submit .new-task": function (event) {

// Prevent default browser form submit
  event.preventDefault();

// Get value from form element
  var name = event.target.name.value;
// Insert a task into the collection
  Tasks.insert({
    name: name,
  });
// Clear form
  event.target.name.value = "";
  }
});
```

Now I want to know a way to do the same thing but to store an image given by an user in a collection (the image file, not the path in the user's PC). Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) package with [GridFS](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/gridfs) storage adapter.